# Oracle sqlplus: relative paths starting at position of script

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sqlplus

When I have two sql-files, one of them in a sub-directory

```
main_test.sql
sub/sub_test.sql
```

and `sub_test.sql`calls `@../main_test.sql` (or `@@../main_test.sql`) then this works fine when executing it from the sub-directory

```
sub> sqlplus xxx @ sub_test.sql
```

But when I call

```
sub> cd ..
> sqlplus xxx @ sub/sub_test.sql
```

this results in

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file "../main_test.sql"
```

since the path is evaluated from my working directory, not the directory of the sql-file I call.

Is there a way to use relative paths starting from the directory of file containing the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shame the 'file' url isn't supported - since this actually works very well when using 'http://' paths !

I set up 'sub_test\sub_test.sql' to contain the double-ats:

```
@@../main.sql
```

put the whole directory structure under a Tomcat webapps/ROOT context and it works if you call like this:

```
SQL> @http://host:port/sub_test/sub_test.sql
```

Probably a bit of overkill setting up a web-server I guess ?? (Also works with FTP apparently - not tried it).

Comment: Thanks for trying and sharing :) As I don't really need this, I don't think I'm going to set up a web-server though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way of achieving this I'm afraid, but it does illustrate one of the problems of this hosted script approach.

I remember back when I started with Oracle in v7.1.whatever we would use scripts for almost everything, but there were so many tasks that could only be achieved with external scripts that you might as well use them for everything. However I think that there have been fewer reasons to do so with every release, and the only ones I have now would be refactored to pl/sql with 11g.

Comment: Do you mean DDL as part of a new code deployment, or as part of a regular batch job (for example).

Answer (score 1):

(It looks to me like the filename in the line with the SP2-0310 error was mis-typed.  I believe that the file you meant to indicate was "../main_test.sql" and I'll proceed along that line).

If you're in the directory containing main_test.sql and you execute sub/sub_test.sql, and within sub/sub_test.sql you're invoking main_test.sql as "../main_test.sql", yes, you're going to get an error because your current working directory is the one that contains main_test.sql, so looking up one directory level by using ".." isn't going to work.  In this case you'll either need to remove the ".." or use "." (single period - indicates current directory) to get things to work.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! I know that changing it to "." would help in that case, but then it would not work from the main directory of course. What I was thinking of is a way to tell the script not to take the current working directory for relative paths, but the directory where the script actually is located. The script "knows" where the other scripts are compared to its own position, and I would like it not to consider my current working directory which is not relevant...